# For loop with ASync and then wait for it to complete (Obj-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, dispatch-async

So let's assume I have the following code

```
-(void)doSomething{
   [self expensiveMethod];
   [self otherMethod]; //Depends on above method to have finished
}

-(void)expensiveMethod{
 for(int i = 0; i<[someArray count]; i++{
     [self costlyOperation:someArray[i]];
  }
}
```

Ideally I want `[self costlyOperation]` to spin off other threads so that each one is done as close to parallel (of course I realize this isn't exactly possible). Once the `[self costlyOperation]` has been done on each array object I'd like it to return so that `[self otherMethod` can take advantage of the processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use default queue to run tasks in the background using dispatch async.

**EDIT**

You can group async tasks for parallel asyc execution. You might have to tweak it a bit as per your requirement.

```
-(void)doSomething{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){
        //Background Thread
        [self expensiveMethod:^{
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                //Run UI Updates
                [self otherMethod]; //Depends on above method to have finished
            });
        }];
    });
}

-(void)expensiveMethod:(void (^)(void))callbackBlock {

    dispatch_group_t group = dispatch_group_create();

    for(int i = 0; i<[someArray count]; i++) {
        __block int index = i;
        dispatch_group_async(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {
            [self costlyOperation:someArray[index]];
        });
    }

    dispatch_group_notify(group,dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^ {
        if (callbackBlock) {
            callbackBlock();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Well that kind of answers some portion of it. The other portion is inside `expensiveMethod` where I want to run the for loop processing in parallel.

Comment: thanks! Question: Is there a limit to the number of threads I can have?

Comment: It's not necessary that each asyn task runs in a separate thread. All of the dispatch queue priorities are concurrent queues and can do parallel processing but still they are queues.